# Visual Studio Code C++ color formatting in type declarations

Tags: visual-studio-code, tmlanguage

[image]

As you can see, in C++ type declarations (string and new type), the colors of the types are in normal text color, which I find oddly peculiar, since it isn't the case for java source codes (even using the exact same theme).

I've tried customizing it in user settings:

[image]

But all that does is change the color of the type in the type *definitions*, not in the declarations.

I've also tried out various themes, but it's all the same.

Strangely, this doesn't happen for java source codes as shown in the image below:
[image]

I might be missing something. Maybe there's some field or attribute in the user settings that I should change instead of the 'type'.

Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 2):

According to the `Developer: Inpsect TM scopes` command, the entire `string x` declaration has the same scopes:

- `source.cpp` - the "base" scope for cpp files that everything in them has
- `meta.block.c` - just tells you that it's inside of a block / `{}`

[image]

Consequently, there's not really anything to target with `editor.tokenColorCustomizations`, since that's based on scopes.

You could search for an extension that replaces the built-in CPP grammar with one that is better in this regard. Note that the only one I've found so far, [Reloaded C/C++](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=reloadedextensions.reloaded-cpp), doesn't help. Alternatively, you could search for a better grammar elsewhere - TmLanguage grammars are very commonplace and used in many editors, not just VSCode. Even GitHub uses them for their syntax highlighting.